# Granting a 'normal' user ability to mount a drive (visudo)

Tags: mount, sudo

I am running a server on AWS that requires a storage volume to be mounted on an as-needed basis. I need 'normal' users (those without any sudo privileges etc.) to be able to mount this drive and perform necessary actions.

To do so, I did:

1. Create a group called `xyz`: `sudo groupadd xyz`
2. Added my user to this group: `sudo usermod -a -G xyz sriram`
3. Edited `/etc/sudoers` file like so:

   ```
   %xyz ALL=/bin/mount /dev/xvdg, /bin/umount /dev/xvdg
   ```

However, when I try to mount the drive with:
    mount /dev/xvdg data

I get the error:

```
only root can do that...
```

Adding `sudo` to the above command did not solve issues as user `sriram` is not part of the `wheel` group either.

I also read through some posts online that suggest adding user details in `/etc/fstab`. That would allow me to mount this drive without sudo. However, this is not my use case. I want to be able to mount the drive on an as-needed basis

How do I solve this? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo expects to match the full path of the command. So try

```
sudo /bin/mount /dev/xvdg /data
```

(You will need to add the " /data" part to your sudo line also).

Comment: `sudo` does the PATH lookup, `sudo mount /dev/xvdg /data` would work. The missing `/data` in the sudo configuration is the problem.

Comment: @Uditha: Thank you for your reply. I was missing the destination folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a line in `/etc/fstab` which describes how to mount volumes. Reading the page displayed with `man fstab` you should take a look at the `user` option. This solution does not use `sudo`, but I assume your ultimate goal is to allow regular users to mount the drive.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This drive is not mounted with `/etc/fstab` at all. I am using AWS.

Comment: From what I read on [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html), point 7, `fstab` is used as well. The `user` option should probably be added after `defaults,nofail` in their example. The file `fstab` is not only meant for volumes mounted at startup, it can also describe mounts of the kind you need. You can use the `noauto` option to specifically prevent automatic mounting.